# YAML file range, converting string to array throwing undefined method `to_a'

Tags: arrays, ruby, range, yaml

I have a YAML file that contains a bunch of ranges as the values:

```
combat_power:
  Bulbasaur: (12.2..1071)
  Ivysaur: (19.5..1632)
  Venusaur: (32.2..2580)
  Charmander: (10.7..955)
  Charmeleon: (18.5..1557)
  Charizard: (32.5..2602)
  Squirtle: (11.4..1008)
  Wartortle: (18.9..1582)
  Blastoise: (31.7..2542)
  Caterpie: (4.3..443)
  Metapod: (4.7..477)
  Butterfree: (17.2..1454)
```

While attempting to turn these ranges into an array I am getting an error: `<main>': undefined method to_a'`

How I am attempting to do this is very simple:

```
require 'yaml'

data = YAML.load_file('./lib/lists/yamls/combat_power.yml')

print 'Enter a name: '
name = gets.chomp.capitalize

new_data = data['combat_power'][name]

puts new_data.to_a
```

When this is run:

```
Enter a name: Charmeleon
go.rb:10:in `<main>': undefined method `to_a' for "(18.5..1557)":String (NoMetho
dError)
Did you mean?  to_yaml
               to_f
               to_r
               to_i
               to_s
               to_c
```

My question being, how do I turn a range key into an array when it is being provided from a YAML file? Any other way you can just turn a range into an array using the `to_a` function, but it doesn't appear to be working. Is there a simple solution I am missing, or are ranges not allowed to be used in YAML files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

1. Ruby's YAML implementation doesn't unserialize ruby objects without you explicitly telling it to do so. This is both a security feature (some code is dangerous to unserialize), as well as a somewhat impossible task to accomplish (how is it supposed to know what you intend to be evaluated?). So, to turn the range string into an actual Ruby `Range` object, you need to `eval` it:

   ```
   require 'yaml'

   data = YAML.load_file('./yamls.yaml')

   print 'Enter a name: '
   name = gets.chomp.capitalize

   new_data = data['combat_power'][name]

   puts eval(new_data).class
   # => Range
   puts eval(new_data).to_a
   ```

   Note that you should only `eval` text that you explicitly wrote--`eval`ing code from a random source, such as user input, can be a serious security issue. But as long as you are only `eval`ing values from that YAML file that you wrote, you should be fine.
2. Ruby doesn't know how to enumerate a range of floats, so your `(17.2..1454).to_a` will throw a `TypeError`. This is because the interpreter can't possibly know if you want to increment by `+1`, `+0.1`, etc. I'm not sure how you want to solve this issue, since the solution will be based on the meaning of your data specifically.

Comment: That's even better then the answer I found: `!ruby/range <range>` do you have a link to the `eval` docs?

Comment: Don't ever use eval unless you *really* have to and there is *absolutely zero chance* there will ever be user-supplied data in the `eval`ed code. But even then: don't use eval. It's a way too sharp sword for almost all problems.

Comment: Agreed, unless your problem is "I need to parse this string of Ruby code".